# Does any Japanese dialect use the schwa?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, phonology, vowels

Pronunciation of [ə] is notoriously difficult for Japanese speakers, and while trying to communicate its importance in languages such as English and French, I started to wonder: **do any dialects of Japanese employ the schwa, or some approximation of it?**

Answer (score 5):

There is a dialect of Ryūkyūan employing [ə]:

“The Yaeyama Taketomi-jima dialect has a six-vowel system: *a, ə, i, u, o, e.* <…> *_ə_ is a vowel found only in the Taketom-jima dialect…*”

(Handbook of the Ryukyuan Languages)

This implies also the fact that [ə] is notoriously rare even for Ryūkyūan.

Comment: 印象的！Given what's said about the lexical distance between even 鹿児島弁 and Ryūkyūan, I guess there won't be many speakers of 標準語 who know Ryūkyūan well enough for me to usefully reference it. Could be an amusing thing to mention though.